# RegEx for matching a string before a year1

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, split

I have directory names which include year numbers. I want to split them to variables what is before the year number:

#### Input:

```
Holidays.uS.2019.bla.bla
Holidays.ca.old.2017.bla.bla
Holidays.2015.bla.bla.bla
Holidays.1.2.3.4.at.old.1999.bla.bla.bla.bla
```

The year is not always in the same place, but, it always has 4 digits.

I always need everything up to the year.

For an input:

```
Holidays.ca.old.2017.bla.bla
```

#### Output:

```
Holidays.ca.old
```

#### Attempt

```
set name Holidays.ca.old.2017.bla.bla
set numbers [regexp -all -inline {[0-9]+} $name]
```

Output from my code is the year number, and sometimes other wrong numbers.

I use this in tcl and it works perfectly for me:

```
set name_split [regsub {\.[0-9]{4}\y.*} $name ""]
```

I still need it for a bash script, how can use it?

This does not really work in bash:

```
name_split=$(echo $name | {\.[0-9]{4}\y.*}
```

Comment: Note that my answer below is a direct conversion of my previous Tcl solution. `\y` is `\b` or (here) `\>`. In some seds, these might fail to work, so I added an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `sed`:

```
name="Holidays.uS.2019.bla.bla"
name_split="$(sed 's/\.[0-9]\{4\}\>.*//' <<< $name)"
echo $name_split
```

Output: `Holidays.uS`, see the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/Za1S1t).

Note: if there must be a dot after  year, it makes sense to match it rather than rely on a word boundary:

```
name_split="$(sed 's/\.[0-9]\{4\}\..*//' <<< $name)"
                                 ^^
```

The `sed` command here means:

- `s/` - substitute:
- `\.`  - a dot
- `[0-9]\{4\}` - four digits
- `\>` - a trailing word boundary
- `.*` - the rest of the string

with an empty string.

Comment: cool big thx, and how can i set the year to variable? big thx, Regards

Comment: @MikeShiwa Use `year="$(sed 's/.*\.\([0-9]\{4\}\)\>.*/\1/' <<< $name)"`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/jFfQmb).

Answer (score 1):

You might add additional boundaries in your `sed` command, just to be safe and pass the chars that you wish:

#### Code

```
#!/bin/bash
STRING="Holidays.1.2.3.4.at.old.1999.bla.bla.bla.bla"
MATCH="$(sed 's/\([A-z0-9\.]*\)\(\.[0-9]\{4\}.*\)$/\1/' <<< $STRING)"
echo $MATCH
```

#### Output

```
Holidays.1.2.3.4.at.old
```

#### Special Chars

If you do not wish to pass special chars, [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/GogpTY/1/) is safe:

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how it works

[image]

#### Performance

This snippet shows the performance of the expression with a 1-million times repeat.

```js
repeat = 1000000;
start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 var string = "Holidays.1.2.3.4.at.old.1999.bla.bla.bla.bla";
 var regex = /^([A-z0-9\.]*)(\.[0-9]{4}.*)/g;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$1");
}

end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: pictorial explanation via graphs is very helpful, makes things easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `sed`:

```
echo "Holidays.ca.old.2017.bla.bla" | sed 's/^\(.*\)\.[0-9]\{4\}.*$/\1/';

Holidays.ca.old
```

The regex simply captures everything up until the *last* dot followed by a four digit year, then replaces with just that captured quantity:

```
(.*)        match and capture everything up until
\.[0-9]{4}  a literal dot, followed by a four digit year
.*          consume the remainder of the input
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way which doesn't use `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash
test_str="Holidays.ca.old.2017.bla.bla"
reg_ex='^(.*)\.([0-9]{4})' # Easy to read reg_ex vs sed reg_ex gibberish
if [[ $test_str =~ $reg_ex ]]
then
  echo "1: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  echo "2: ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
```

Output:

1: Holidays.ca.old

2: 2017

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ str='Holidays.1.2.3.4.at.old.1999.bla.bla.bla.bla'
$ echo "${str%.[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*}"
Holidays.1.2.3.4.at.old
```

This removes a period, followed by four digits and then anything to the end of the string (the `*` wildcard).